# Look for specified place type with OpenStreetMap and Nominatim

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap, reverse-geocoding, nominatim

In my app, I use Leaflet with OpenStreetMap. I also use Nominatim to get place details. I want to check whether the place is gas station.
But, when I point to gas station, and get place details, the JSON file often have different "type" property.
It can be:

```
type: "fuel"   <-- this is great
or
type: "convenience"
or
type: "yes"
or maybe even other
```

Can I, somehow, specify if place is really a gas station?

Example JSON output for a GAS STATION
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2&lat=50.0487556&lon=21.999057381458194

```
place_id: 143194204, licence: "Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright", osm_type: "way", osm_id: 230603036, lat: "50.0487556", …}
place_id: 143194204
licence: "Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright"
osm_type: "way"
osm_id: 230603036
lat: "50.0487556"
lon: "21.999057381458194"
place_rank: 30
category: "shop"
type: "convenience"
importance: 0
addresstype: "shop"
name: "Orlen"
display_name: "Orlen, 10, Warszawska, 1000-Lecia, Rzeszów, województwo podkarpackie, 35-205, Polska"
address: {convenience: "Orlen", house_number: "10", road: "Warszawska", suburb: "1000-Lecia", city: "Rzeszów", …}
boundingbox: (4) ["50.0486885", "50.0488243", "21.9989449", "21.9991699"]
__proto__: Object
```

I considered using Google Places API with Geocoding API, but Geocoding requires billing account, so I'd not use that.

EDIT:

Thanks to below comment, I managed to get raw data from OSM by using osm_id from nominatim reverse geocoding call. Just use:
`http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];way(MY_OSM_ID);out;`

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. It's not entirely clear what you are asking here? If you are asking: "Do you have a database which contains information about whether a location is a gas station or not"? If so, then I don't think StackOverflow is the right place to ask. Consider taking the tour (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn a bit more about the types of questions that are typically asked and answered here.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to get more detailed place description, with more tags, or maybe I can use different API to get place details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [object from your question](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/230603036) is both a gas station and a convenience shop. It is [tagged](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag) as [`amenity=fuel`](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:amenity%3Dfuel) and [`shop=convenience`](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:shop%3Dconvenience). However Nominatim has to decide which `type` to print and apparently convenience has a higher priority than fuel.

If you want to check the tags of a specific object then Nominatim is probably the wrong choice. Nominatim is a geocoder, intended for converting names into geographic coordinates (geocoding) or vice-versa (reverse-geocoding). If you already know the OSM ID and [element](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements) type then you can download its raw data directly from OSM to check all original tags. If you just know the rough location then you could use [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) to download specific POIs (e.g. fuel stations) in this area.